# How to render react components based on an ACL object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux, acl

I have a an object as bellow for user `ACl(Access Control list)`:

```js
{
  'api/modelA': ['GET', 'POST'],
  'api/modelB': ['GET'],
  /*...*/
  'api/modelZ' : ['GET']
}
```

So after user is authenticated I get the `ACLs` from server.
How can I find a solution for rendering all the components based on these `ACls`. for instance if user doesn't have access to edit a post the `EditButtom` component should not be rendered.

Note: for some cases a component will have a different style like gray color if there is no access for the user.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a higher order component on the component(say EditButton).

```
function HOC(Component) {
   if(ACL(model).indexOf("POST)
   return   <Component style={{display: none}} />;

   return <Component {...this.props}>;
 }

 render(){
   const HocButton = HOC(EditButton); // EditButton  is some button 

   return (<EditButton>Edit</EditButton>;
 }
```